# Why is my XSD not validating some elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am trying to define an XML Schema for a recursive data structure. Basically an element should be able to have children and properties, which is a list of elements that may in turn have children and properties. An "element" may be one of a range of type, all with the possibility of having children and properties in addition to some extra data. Thus, the element types are arranged in inherit from the `BaseElementType` and add their own data on top.

I have made some progress but have run into an issue with with the validator accepting pretty much anything when moving down the structure.

My schema is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/ElementSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org/ElementSchema">


    <xs:element name="BaseElement" type="BaseElementType" />
    <xs:element name="DoubleElement" type="DoubleElementType" />
    <xs:element name="BoundedDoubleElement" type="BoundedDoubleElementType" />


    <xs:element name="Properties" type="ElementList" />
    <xs:element name="Children" type="ElementList" />

    <xs:complexType name="ElementList">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="BaseElement" />
            <xs:element name="DoubleElement" />
            <xs:element name="BoundedDoubleElement" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BaseElementType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Children" type="ElementList" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="Properties" type="ElementList"
                minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ID" type="xs:positiveInteger" use="required" />
        <xs:attribute name="Key" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="DoubleElementType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="BaseElementType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:float" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BoundedDoubleElementType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="DoubleElementType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="DesiredValue" type="xs:float" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is an XML file that I am trying to validate. I have inserted the tags `<wrongAccepted>` and `<wrongRejected>` several places to demonstrate where the validation behaves as expected and where it accepts illegal tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<t:BoundedDoubleElement ID="12" Key="test"
    xmlns:t="http://www.example.org/ElementSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/ElementSchema ElementSchema.xsd">
    <Children>
        <BaseElement ID="13" Key="child">
            <Properties>
                <DoubleElement ID="10" Key="Null">
                    <Value>-INF</Value>
                    <wrongAccepted></wrongAccepted>
                </DoubleElement>
                <wrongAccepted></wrongAccepted>
            </Properties>
        </BaseElement>
        <wrongRejected></wrongRejected>
    </Children>
    <Properties>
        <wrongRejected></wrongRejected>
        <DoubleElement ID="10" Key="Null" Role="LowerBound" Tag="-1">
            <Value>-INF</Value>
            <wrongAccepted></wrongAccepted>
        </DoubleElement>
        <DoubleElement ID="11" Key="Null" Role="UpperBound" Tag="-1">
            <Value>INF</Value>
        </DoubleElement>
    </Properties>
    <Value>10</Value>
    <DesiredValue>10</DesiredValue>
    <wrongRejected></wrongRejected>
</t:BoundedDoubleElement>
```

So how do I get it working such that it will reject the invalid tags?

Note: I am testing this in eclipse. I initially had some issues with getting it to validate at all, however it seems to be working now. Additionally the validator in Notepad++ yield exactly the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
        <xs:element name="DoubleElement" />
```

to

```
        <xs:element name="DoubleElement" type="DoubleElementType"/>
```

Otherwise, you're effectively allowing `DoubleElement` to allow any content because the default for `xs:element/@type` (absent child `simplyType`, child `complexType`, and `@substitutionGroup` attribute) is [**ur-type definition**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#ur-type-itself) (*anyType*).

You probably want to do the same for the other children of `ElementList`.

Comment: Jesus Christ. Thank you. So simple! I have been staring at it for way too long.